# iOS - Error message "no space left on device"

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, afnetworking

We suddenly experience a problem that somehow seems to be related to iOS 14 as we haven't had those errors in prior versions.

At app start, we do quite a lot of network requests to different webservices. This sums up to 158 GET, POST and PUT requests until a user is fully logged in. The app uses 260MB of memory until then. When a user switches to a different account, the login process starts again and another 158 requests are sent out. Now if the user again decides to login with a new account, the login procedure starts yet again. But this time, network requests randomly start canceling with such error messages:

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=28 "No space left on device" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <EA2DAE7D-F7AD-4979-8215-E716163FA725>.<1>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <EA2DAE7D-F7AD-4979-8215-E716163FA725>.<1>"), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=28}
```

So within a timeframe of two minutes and approximately 400 - 500 HTTP requests, the network layer starts canceling those due to a lack of memory space. Although it could use up 3GB.

The app network logic hasn't changed much before and after we started experiencing such errors. We are also using one SessionManager instance only. It seems to me as if the network stack would start drowning by the number of requests and therefore starts canceling them. Perhaps iOS 14 became more strict in such regards? Has anyone else possibly experienced a similar issue?

We use AFNetworking on our basic network layer.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while of investigation, it turned out to be a library we're using for debugging purposes. This library, DBDebugToolkit, comes with a network logger feature which we had turned on by default. In situations of high traffic, network logger quickly increased memory usage until our requests got canceled. Now it's turned off by default, but can be switched on in our debugging menu.